# Mule DevKit Connectors, Connection Management and reconnect policies

Tags: mule

Should a custom Mule connector written using the DevKit be compatible by default with reconnection policies.  e.g., I wrote a connector using connection management following http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Implementing+Connection+Management

When I set up an error condition and my @Connect method throws a ConnectionException my flow stops and the connector doesn't try to reconnect despite having a global config element:

```
<configuration>
    <reconnect-forever frequency="2000"/>
</configuration>
```

I know this config is working because it has the expected effect on a JDBC transport but not on my custom connector.

Am I missing something fundamental?  Should custom connectors work at all with reconnect-forever policies?

I'm using Mule 3.4 CE and DevKit 3.4

Thanks for any help or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: It should work unless... bug? Could you try with 3.5.0 CE?

Comment: Hi David.  I hoped that wasn't the answer (operator error would be better)...  I will give it a go.  May take a little while to get to it.

Comment: So no joy with 3.5.0 CE.  When the @Connect method fails an error is thrown like below but then a reconnect is never attempted:

  ERROR 2014-06-26 09:25:04,227 [Receiving Thread] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: The security token included in the request is invalid...
  ERROR 2014-06-26 09:25:04,228 [Receiving Thread] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: ...

Do you know of any DevKit based connectors where this does work ok?

Comment: Not in particular, I was convinced this was working OOTB.

Answer (score 3):

In DevKit, in order for your operations to trigger the reconnection mechanism you need to mark the processor with the @ReconnectOn annotation, and specify the exception that will trigger the reconnection.

```
@Processor
@ReconnectOn(exceptions = {TypeAException.class, TypeBException.class})
public boolean fooProcessor(String param) 
                         throws TypeAException, TypeBException, TypeCException;
```

In this example the exception of TypeCException will not trigger the reconnection, the others will.

If your @ValidateConnection method returns true, the @Connect won't be called again.